# Menu bar and context menu are missing from some apps on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, menu-bar, context-menu

I have got a problem in Skype and Slack on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Perhaps this problem exists in other applications as well. As you may see in the following screenshots, the menu bars and context menus are missing from these apps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please be so kind and replace the screenshots in your question with new ones that display your problem better? The current ones don't seem very enlightening about your issue.